# Get logs from both my application and Tornado

Tags: python, logging, tornado

I'm a bit confused about Tornado's logging feature.

I've tried to use a boilerplate template to set up a simple tornado app with a logging functionality:

https://github.com/bueda/tornado-boilerplate/blob/master/settings.py

```
LOGGERS = {
   'loggers': {
        'boilerplate': {},
    },
}
```

And I then setup and use the logger in the files where I need it :

```
logger = logging.getLogger('boilerplate.' + __name__)

...

logger.info("Function X blahblah")
```

Now this all works great for the logging messages that I've set up, but all the logging from tornado (info about routes, verbose error logs...) is gone.

I've tried adding "tornado" to the LOGGERS dict hoping that it might capture the `tornado.application` and `tornado.general` loggers but to no avail.

```
LOGGERS = {
   'loggers': {
        'boilerplate': {},
        'tornado' : {}
    },
}
```

How can I make sure that the logs from Tornado are also recorded?

Answer (score 0):

As far as tornado's logging is based on the default pythonic, i think you should define a `root` section in your config, just like [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes) , e.g.:

```py
        ...
        'root': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', 'file', 'errors']
        },
```